# Deploy a asp.net core web application with sql db to azure using visual studio team services

Tags: sql-server, azure

How to deploy a asp.net core web application with sql db to azure using visual studio team services(VSTS). Application is using entity framework code first approach.

Comment: A complete step by step tutorial can be found here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/examples/azure/aspnet-core10-azure-web-apps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a challenging question that falls into the topic of continous integration. It takes a bit of time.

1. from VS you have set up TFS for pointing your VSTS account and project and the code first to install its changes when deployed at the first launch (application start event).
2. on VSTS project account, you have set up building feature for launch a build after, let's suppose, a commit on server.
3. on VSTS project account, you have set up your azure web app account profile from the administration panel of the account (you have the xml file with the references to the web app account and password).
4. on VSTS project account, you have set up deploy features that make also substitution at fly of the environment connection string (I've done in this way..) and that points to the azure web app account profile you have created on VSTS.
5. make a commit from your VS and, if all it is done right, then you'll find your code and db changes on azure.

Describing the whole process, would require a substantial article and the relative time to do it. But you can find help googling around (most posts are on StackOverflow) and posting question step by step as you go forward to do this process.